# $ \frac{1}{n} $ is cauchy w.r.t $ |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove that $ \frac{1}{n}  $ is cauchy w.r.t $ |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| .$

I have tried as let $\{x_n\}=\frac{1}{n}$.  If the sequence is cauchy w.r.t the given matrix  then

$\forall\ \varepsilon >0\ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\ $ s.t. $ \forall\ n,m\ge n_0 ,$  $|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x_m}|<\varepsilon. $

Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2} $

And take $n=n_0$ and $ m=n_{0+1}$, then clearly, $  \Big|\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n_0}}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n_{0+1}}} \Big|=|1| >\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the metric is $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{m} |$, then let's look at the negation of the Cauchy condition:

$\exists \epsilon > 0 \, \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \,$ s.t $ m,n > N $ AND $ d(x_n,x_m) \geq \epsilon$

WLOG let $n = m+1$, then $d(x_n,x_m) = |1 | > 1 $, so it suffices to choose $\epsilon = 1.$

I think you have done something similar, but it is usually safer to work with the negation.